# Given a string of integers find out all the possible words that can made out of it in continuous order.

Tags: java, combinations, sequences

Given a string of integers how to find out all the possible words that can made out of it in continuous order. Eg: 11112

ans: AAAAB
AKAB
AAKB
AAAL etc.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="11111124";
    char strChar[]=str.toCharArray();
    String target="";
    for(int i=0;i<strChar.length;i++)
    {
        target=target+(char)Integer.parseInt(""+(16+strChar[i]));
    }
    System.out.println(target);
}
```

i am trying to find the solution for this but not able to find all combination

Comment: How do you define a word using the numbers? Is 'ans' the answer for 11112?

Comment: yes 1 is equivalent to A

Comment: Don't see relationship between `11112` and `AKAB`.

Comment: @Andreas 1 = a 11 = k 1 = a 2 = b

Comment: I also don't see anything in the code that even tries to find the `AKAB`, `AAKB`, `AAAL` combinations. You need to take a stab at the problem and then ask if you run into a *specific* problem.

Comment: second time it will be work like 11 as k 12 as l and so on

Comment: @NicholasRobinson How do you determine the difference between two 1s and a single 11..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think that's what the question is asking.

Comment: That's obscure. Try reading the lesson/task again.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Not sure you *do*, that "etc" after the examples suggests that `KKB` might well be valid in addition to `AAAAB`.

Comment: @devendrak353 It can be solved easily with recursion. Of course it can also be solved by using loops, just that the code will be much longer.

Comment: Take a look at dynamic programming & recursion probably...

Comment: The question seems much more complex to me..  Let's say we have the String `1124`, then OP wants a list of all possible combintions of the letters, with a length from 1 though 4, containing `A` (1), `K` (11), `L` (12), `B` (2), `D` (4), `W` (24)..

Comment: yes this is what i am saying

Comment: Just to see if I understand, `163` can be `1,6,3` or `16,3`, but not `1,63`, because there are only 26 letters. Is this correct?

Comment: yes if it is beyond 26 then have to ignore it

Comment: So with `1124`, these are valid: `A`, `B`, `D`, `K`, `L`, `W`, `AA`, `AB`, `AK`, `AW`, `BA`, `BK`, etc. etc. up to `DBAA`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I get the feeling you have to use all the numbers in each word

Comment: @NicholasRobinson I've got the feeling the question is a bit unclear and needs an edit..

Comment: it should be in word every time all integer should be used

Comment: @user3437460 Kudos for suggesting recursion. I used it in my answer.

Comment: @Andreas You are welcomed. The credit is yours for spending time writing the codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining the comments saying that `163` can be `1,6,3` or `16,3`, but not `1,63`, and *user3437460*'s suggestion of using recursion:

1. Take first digit and convert to letter. Make recursive call using letter and remaining digits.
2. Take first two digits. If `<=26`, convert to letter and make recursive call using letter and remaining digits.

Here is the code. Since I have no clue what to call the method, I'm going with `x`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    x("11112", "");
    System.out.println("------");
    x("163", "");
}
private static final void x(String digits, String word) {
    if (digits.isEmpty())
        System.out.println(word);
    else {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(digits.substring(0, 1));
        x(digits.substring(1), word + (char)('A' + num - 1));
        if (digits.length() >= 2 && (num = Integer.parseInt(digits.substring(0, 2))) <= 26)
            x(digits.substring(2), word + (char)('A' + num - 1));
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
AAAAB
AAAL
AAKB
AKAB
AKL
KAAB
KAL
KKB
------
AFC
PC
```

Comment: thanks a lot this is what i want to do :)